# VB.NET class members public by default

Tags: vb.net

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dc6we3z.aspx):

> Public access is the normal level for a programming element when you
>   do not need to limit access to it. Note that the access level of an
>   element declared within an interface, module, class, or structure
>   defaults to Public if you do not declare it otherwise.

So, if I declare a class method in VB.NET without specifying an access modifier, then it is public by default:

```
Sub DoSomething()

End Sub
```

This is insane! I want members to be private by default, and only those specifically marked as Public to be visible outside the class. Like in C#...  How do I modify this behaviour?

Comment: why is typing 'private' so onerous?

Comment: Personally I think implicit access modifiers is a bad idea as a whole. The code will be much more clear for other readers if you always explicitly include the access modifier.

Comment: @MitchWheat - desired programming philosophy: language defaults should be "conservative"; not good for a type to expose stuff that is not intended to be exposed. REQUIRING a programmer to do something, that they shouldn't need to do, is a sub-optimal solution. That's what we have computers for: to make it easier for people. Granted, one could solve this at the IDE level: have the IDE automatically add "Private", unless a modifier is specified.

Comment: @MitchWheat Agreed. IMO, the default/undeclared property access modifier should simply follow the class declaration. So in `Friend Class MyClass`, `Property MyProp As Object` should default to `Friend`, in `Private Class MyClass`, `Property MyProp As Object` should default to `Private`, etc. This seems fairly obvious and intuitive to me. It makes no sense that a private class should/can have anything other than private members.

Comment: @SteveCinq That doesn't make a lot of sense. The members of a class are never visible outside the scope that the class itself is visible. The members of a Friend class aren't visible outside the assembly even if you declare them Public; they are effectively Friend by default already. The members of a Private class aren't visible anywhere the class itself isn't visible, even if they are Public members.
This ultimately is an issue of "behavior of least surprise." The amount of typing is a red herring. The only reason this is an issue is because you expect the default to be Private and it's not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> This is insane! I want members to be private by default

As Fredrik has already commented, you should always provide explicit access modifiers.

> The code will be much more clear for other readers if you always
>   explicitly include the access modifier.

I assume that this is due to downwards compatibility or developers who are not familiar with access modifiers at all.

But you are right, as in C# I would suggest to make everything as private as possible by default. You can make it more public when needed.

*[Declaration Contexts and Default Access Levels (VB.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235296%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)*

> Any idea how to modify this behaviour?

I don't think that it's possible to specify the default access modifier somewhere in Visual Studio. You could try to create a template-class which is suggested here (not tested):

*[Visual C# 2010 Express: Specify default access modifier for new classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4975378/284240)*

Answer (score 0):

Visual Basic 6 properties and methods were by default Public.  As VB.NET was the successor to VB6, I believe the decision was made to continue this behaviour.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa266191(v=vs.60)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

As for the topic of modifying the behaviour in VB.NET - other than changing the templates or creating a Macro to find/replace, there is no way to achieve this.

(Yes, I know this is a very old topic)